# Python netcdf Aemet

Tags: python, netcdf4

Estoy intentando trabajar con la regilla de 5 km de la Aemet (http://www.aemet.es/es/serviciosclimaticos/cambio_climat/datos_diarios?w=2&w2=0) con la regilla de 20-50 km lo hago sin problema.
 No lo consigo por que las coordenas longitud y latitud estan en un sistema de referencia que desconozco de hecho su nombre completo es "... in rotated pole grid"

```
import xarray as xr 
dataset = xr.open_dataset(r'C:\Users\eg\Desktop\nec\sfcan20120101a20121231_rot_mask.nc')
dataset

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (height: 1, rlat: 240, rlon: 280, time: 366)
Coordinates:
* rlon           (rlon) float64 -5.0 -4.95 -4.9 -4.85 ... 8.8 8.85 8.9 8.95
* rlat           (rlat) float64 -6.45 -6.4 -6.35 -6.3 ... 5.35 5.4 5.45 5.5
* height         (height) float64 0.0
* time           (time) datetime64[ns] 2012-01-01T06:00:00 ... 2012-12-     
 31T06:00:00
 Data variables:
rotated_pole   |S1 ...
precipitation  (time, height, rlat, rlon) float32 ...
lon            (rlat, rlon) float32 ...
lat            (rlat, rlon) float32 ...
Attributes:
title:        AEMET High-resolution (0.05 deg) daily gridded precipitatio...
institution:  Agencia Estatal de Meteorologia (AEMET, www.aemet.es)
references:   Peral, C., Navascu�s, B., Ramos, P. Available at: http://ww...
history:      Creation year 2017
Conventions:  CF-1.7
version:      1.0
```

El problema esta en que las coordenadas del ncdf en vez de ir aproximadamente de -10 a 4 en longitud y 35 a 44 en latitud van de -5 a 8.95 en longitud y de -6.45 a 8.45 en latitud
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si miras la informacion del netcdf, e.g.

```
ncdump -h ~/Serie_AEMET_v1_pcp_2010a2017_netcdf/sfcan20120101a20121231_rot_mask.nc
```

Te da las coordenadas del rotated pole:

```
    char rotated_pole ;
            rotated_pole:grid_mapping_name = "rotated_latitude_longitude" ;
            rotated_pole:grid_north_pole_latitude = 49.5 ;
            rotated_pole:grid_north_pole_longitude = -186. ;
```

Esa información la puedes usar en herramientas como ncl para proyectar correctamente el netcdf: https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/rotatedltln.shtml